# brightness control not working in 14.04 (dell inspiron 3537)

Tags: 14.04, dell, brightness, inspiron

brightness control not working when keys are pressed with Fn key. it shows indicator on top
right corner increasing & decreasing but nothing happens.

Comment: tried so many answers which is answered for similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to find out which ACPI interface controls the brighntess, for that run this command in the terminal

**grep acpi_video /var/log/Xorg.0.log**

Above command should display something like this

[
7.385] (--) intel(0): Found backlight control interface **acpi_videoX**

Now find out what is your ACPI interface. It may be **acpi_video0" or "acpi_video1"**

If above command does not display anything then your ACPI is **intel_backlight**.  You can use it as your ACPI for nest steps.

Now set your laptop brighness using brightness keys whether it does't work, to aspect ed brightness you use. Now you have to find out actual brightness value which you set. For that enter this command in terminal  cat

/sys/class/backlight/**acpi_videoX**/brightness

You need to replace your laptop ACPI to bolded place.

Now you will see the actual brightness level. Remember it for next steps.

Now we will have to create a file at /etc/init/ for configurations.

**sudo gedit /etc/init/fixbrightness.conf**

Now paste this to opend text file without quotes.

"description "Sets brightness after graphics device is loaded"

start on graphics-device-added
task
exec /bin/echo **BRIGHTNESS_VALUE**> /sys/class/backlight/**acpi_videoX**/brightness"

You have to replace **BRIGHTNESS_VALUE** with actual brightness you get and **acpi_videoX** with your laptop's ACPI. Save the file and reboot the laptop and find out weather the problem is fixed. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. works fine now. thanks again..

Comment: If you pleased with my answer, please accept it as the correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The file `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` contains the brightness information.

So you can just set the desired brightness by a command like this:

```
echo 500 >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

(the range of brightness is generally up to 950).